# How to test which cell in a pandas dataframe string column contains a substring of a given reference string?

Tags: python, string, pandas, substring

I am dealing with a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
0 Item         Category
1 Hammer       A
2 Car          A
3 Cardiologist B
4 Park         A
5 Parkway      A
6 CarparkCar   A
```

I need to find all cells in `Item` that contain a specific sequence of letters, defined as substring of my reference word. I am not interested in cells that contain additional letters not present in my reference word.

```
reference_word = Carpark
```

Desired output:

```
0 Item         Category   Contains_substring_of_reference_word
1 Hammer       A          FALSE
2 Car          A          TRUE
3 Cardiologist B          FALSE
4 Park         A          TRUE
5 Parkway      A          FALSE
6 CarparkCar   A          TRUE
```

**How to check which cell of a pandas dataframe column contains a substring of a given word/string?**

Comment: Use apply and indexof method to do this

Comment: let me kindly ask if it is possible to be more specific (i.e. include a link or some code)

Comment: @sudonym Yes, it is possible. Take a look at my answer. Keep in mind that set operations (what you're looking for) are generally slow, no matter what the language or method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
One simple way to do this is using `apply` + `set.issubset` -

```
v = df.Item.str.lower().apply(lambda x: set(x).issubset('carpark'))
v

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
Name: Item, dtype: bool
```

Assign the result back -

```
df['Contains_substring_of_reference_word'] = v
df

           Item Category  Contains_substring_of_reference_word
0        Hammer        A                                 False
1           Car        A                                  True
2  Cardiologist        B                                 False
3          Park        A                                  True
4       Parkway        A                                 False
5    CarparkCar        A                                  True
```

---

**Option 2**
Another solution using `set.difference` operations -

```
(df.Item.str.lower().apply(set) - set('carpark')).str.len() == 0

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
Name: Item, dtype: bool
```

---

**Option 3**
Adding another option with `np.vectorize`, this should be faster.

```
c = set('carpark')
def foo(x):
     return c.issuperset(x.lower())

v = np.vectorize(foo)

v(df.Item)
array([False,  True, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

---

**Timings**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)  

%timeit df.Item.str.lower().apply(lambda x: set(x).issubset('carpark'))
1 loop, best of 3: 927 ms per loop

%timeit (df.Item.str.lower().apply(set) - set('carpark')).str.len() == 0
1 loop, best of 3: 1.13 s per loop

%timeit v(df.Item)
1 loop, best of 3: 497 ms per loop
```

Comment: second solution is nice, is also faster? (+1)

Comment: @jezrael Thanks! Also, good question. I just tried this and it is marginally slower than the first. Interesting!

Comment: @jezrael Your comment encouraged me to find a much faster solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can create sets with a comprehension and use `<=` to signify subset.

```
sets = np.array([set(x.lower()) for x in df.Item.values.tolist()])
df.assign(Bool=sets <= set('carpark'))

           Item Category   Bool
0                              
1        Hammer        A  False
2           Car        A   True
3  Cardiologist        B  False
4          Park        A   True
5       Parkway        A  False
6    CarparkCar        A   True
```

Comment: I removed the assign and tested it. This gives `1 loop, best of 3: 555 ms per loop`. Awesome!